# TypeCasting in RxJS Operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to perform typecasting in the following scenario:

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "not a number")
  .pipe(
    filter((val) => typeof val === "number"),
    map((number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Inside the `map` operator the `number` parameter is of type `number`, because the array values were filtered. However, typescript is not able to pick this up by itself and it says that the type of `number` inside the `map` is `string|number`.
I tried to do typecasting in the following ways, but none of them is working.

**Attempt 1**:

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "string")
  .pipe(
    filter((val) => typeof val === "number") as number,
    map((number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

**Error** -> *Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string | number, unknown>'.ts(2345)*

**Attempt 2:**

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "string")
  .pipe(
    filter((val) => typeof val === "number") as OperatorFunction<number,any>,
    map((number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

**Error** -> *Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<number, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string | number, any>'.
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)*

**Attempt 3:**(set the return type in the pipe)

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "string")
  .pipe<number, number>(
    filter((val) => typeof val === "number"),
    map((number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

**Error** -> *Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<string | number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string | number, number>'.
Type 'Observable<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)*

**(Valid, but too hacky) Attempt 4:**
This attempt is the only one that works, but it looks too hacky, as inside the `map` operator I can set any type to the parameter `number` since the return type of `fitler` was marked as `any` .

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "string")
  .pipe(
    filter((val) => typeof val === "number") as any,
    map((number: number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add typeguard predicate `val is number` to the filter callback to narrow the type

```js
of(1, 2, 3, "string")
  .pipe(
    filter((val): val is number => typeof val === "number"),
    map((number) => number * 2)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

More about type guards in the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

[github issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3125)

Comment: This works: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typecasting-filter-so-74301456?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This looks to be working. The docs for typeguards were updated and it looks like the new version is this [one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: @GeorgianStan thanks, updated the answer with a link to actual docs.